# Bundle install killed message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run bundle install on server machine - digital ocean and it is always gets killed like this:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/rails/car_main/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as
root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.5.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Killed
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue while using DigitalOcean and was resolved by increasing the RAM to 1GB from 512MB.

Alternatively you could create a swap file too, but I chose to increase the RAM.

Comment: Yup, this was exactly for me when using default Vagrant box (512MB) and inside the box nokogiri got killed

Comment: Also get because of vagrant box not being able to finish installing a gem. Increasing ram to 1024mb made it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by RAM shortage.

to make sure this is the problem:
open `htop` while `bundle` is running to see if memory usage goes to 100%

to fix this do one of the following:

A. get more RAM or swap as +haris suggested

B. see what eats your machine RAM and close some services (in my case I was trying to update a service while it was running, and the 2GB machine had not enough RAM to run those two at the same time)